# DataGridView CellFormatting Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I've added a handler for the CellFormatting event on a DataGridView to modify the background color based on the content of the row.

It doesn't seem to be firing even as data gets inserted into the table.  I added the event handler by doubleclicking in the IDE on the CellFormatting event which seemed to create the code properly.

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        // this never gets called
        MessageBox.Show("Event fired");
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot use CellFormating event for your case. It occurs when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display.

Try   CellValueChanged  event instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx)

Or

Select other appropriate event from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4dwfh7x.aspx

Comment: I ended up using the RowsAdded event which captured what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the RowValidated event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }
```

NOTE: This event will fire when you click on rows and when you close the form.